# How to generate C# client from Swagger 1.2 spec?

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation, swagger

There seems to be millions of options out there for every platform, but I'm struggling to find a simple solution for C#. All the ones I have found seem to have given me trouble: either they simply don't work (e.g. http://swaggercodegen.azurewebsites.net/), or only support 2.0 (e.g. [AutoRest](https://github.com/Azure/autorest) and [NSwag](https://github.com/NSwag/NSwag)). Half the tools are not even clear what versions they support :-(

I'm aware of the [official tool](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/), but that requires JDK 7 which is not currently an option for me.

In desperation I have even tried converting the swagger spec to 2.0, but half the conversion tools I tried didn't work, gave conflicting advice, or I couldn't figure out how to use (I found myself knee deep in nodejs very quickly...is this really the brave new world?! Bring back WSDL ;-) ).

Comment: Please move your question to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How long is your 1.2 spec? Maybe post your first API? It shouldn't be hard to convert to 2.0 - I think that's your best bet.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the online swagger codegen to create clients without installing anything:

https://generator.swagger.io/

You would choose POST /gen/clients/{language} and enter a body like this:

```
{
  "options": {},
  "swaggerUrl": "http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json"
}
```

Put your own URL to access the specification.  If you need to pass any options, you can put them in the `options` hash.  The list of available options for C# is also available from the generator:

https://generator.swagger.io/api/gen/clients/csharp-dotnet2

```
{
  "packageName": {
    "opt": "packageName",
    "description": "C# package name (convention: Camel.Case).",
    "type": "string",
    "default": "IO.Swagger"
  },
  "packageVersion": {
    "opt": "packageVersion",
    "description": "C# package version.",
    "type": "string",
    "default": "1.0.0"
  },
  "clientPackage": {
    "opt": "clientPackage",
    "description": "C# client package name (convention: Camel.Case).",
    "type": "string",
    "default": "IO.Swagger.Client"
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot find any documentation that confirms that using the online generator will allow you to use a Swagger 1.2 spec. I'm not saying it's not supported, but I can't find evidence suggesting otherwise.

Comment: The code generator supports 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 2.0 specifications.  If the 1.2 spec is mal-formed, it may not work (there was no validation schema initially with 1.2).  It is based on the `swagger-parser` which automatically converts the spec into 2.0 format, then generates the code.

Comment: not sure what it does (I tried their sample, not even my json), after code being generated it has link to download the code, but link leads to HTTP ERROR 500 with the message  Problem accessing /api/gen/download/d40029be-eda6-4d62-b1ef-d05e2e91a72a. Reason:

    Request failed.

Comment: @fehguy are you sure it supports 1.2? I could not find a way to get it working: {
  "spec": {'1.2'},
  "swaggerUrl": "http://public.je-apis.com",
}

Comment: I've got
Unable to render this definition

The provided definition does not specify a valid version field.

Please indicate a valid Swagger or OpenAPI version field. Supported version fields are swagger: "2.0" and those that match openapi: 3.0.n (for example, openapi: 3.0.0).

Answer (score 1):

NSwag provides multiple options for client generation including a CLI, code, or a Windows application.

[image]

You can [check](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/generate-client-code-with-nswag-studio/) complete article on NSwag